# What's the structure that's a combination of "Time" and "Time differences" called?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

Let's say we call `2021/03/11 12:34:56` a `Time`
And let's call `30 minutes` a `TimeDiff`

Then we have the following operations.

```
Time - Time -> TimeDiff
Time + TimeDiff -> Time
Time - TimeDiff -> Time
TimeDiff + TimeDiff -> TimeDiff
TimeDiff - TimeDiff -> TimeDiff
TimeDiff * Scalar -> TimeDiff
```

Note, we for example, can't add `Time`s. Nor can we multiply `TimeDiff`s with each other but we can multiply `TimeDiff`s by scalars.

Is there a general name for this sort of structure?

`TimeDiff` on it's own I think would just be called a Vector, as you can add, subtract and multiply by scalars.

But what would the combination of `Time+TimeDiff` be called? I feel like this should have a name, as it's a combination that might come up in other places (although I am finding it hard to find as good an example as "time").

Comment: It is called an "affine space" (where "time" need not be 1-dimensional).

Comment: Interesting question, I've never really thought about this from a mathematical sense, only a programming sense (where I still struggle with correctly naming the different concepts).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is called an [affine space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space).

Answer (score 4):

The space of all different possible `Time` is called an *affine space*, and the operation of adding a `TimeDiff` to a `Time` is called a *translation* of (more generally a *vector space action* on) the affine space.

Answer (score 0):

More generally, this kind of structure is called a [torsor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_homogeneous_space). See [*Torsors Made Easy*](https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/torsors.html) by John Baez.

> A torsor is like a group that has forgotten its identity.

An [affine space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space) is a torsor for a [vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space).

> An affine space is like a vector space that has forgotten its origin.